# How to set Application Icon in QT on Symbian?

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

How can I set an app icon in QT on Symbian? I read here http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/appicon.html about hot to set it but it doesn't work for me. I created SVG-Tiny icon(file) and wrote ICON = Resource/ico.svg in the pro file. What is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do it. Works for me. Things to check:

- Have you run qmake and rebuilt the project after editing the .pro file?
- In emulator environment, have you restarted the emulator?

---

- Check that your PKG file has rules to install both yourapp.rsc and yourapp.mif to \resource\apps on target

Comment: Thanks! I don't use the emulator. I run my projects on the real devices (Nokia N97, X6, 5800 ExpressMusic and etc). Yes, I run qmake! But it still doesn't work

Comment: yeah. that was a solution! thanks! All that I need is to include mif file into pkg file.

Comment: For some reason `qmake` did not detect the changes in my `.pro` file, and didn't recreate the `Makefile`. I had to manually delete the `Makefile` so that `qmake` would have to regenerate it, then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the path of icon in your .pro file like this

```
ICON = Resource\ico.svg
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: If the point is about forward/backward slashes, then it doesn't matter. The qmake-generated makefile has them as backward slashes in any case.