# Application icon on Qt 4.6.3 / Symbian S60 5th Edition

Tags: qt, icons, symbian

I am trying to make an icon for my Qt 4.6.3 application, which is currently running on Symbian S60 5th edition. The application runs fine, except for its icon, which I have been unable to set by any means. I have read and tried a number of articles, including [[1]](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-the-symbian-platform), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164130/how-to-set-application-icon-in-qt-on-symbian), [[3]](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS000808_-_Creating_and_adding_an_icon_to_an_S60_3rd_Edition_application), [[4]](http://qt-mobility.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-set-qt-application-icon-and.html) and [[5]](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_create_application_icon%28SVG%29_in_S60_3rd_edition), but in vain. What could I be doing wrong, or what should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to `qmake`. For some reason (possibly related to DST changes), it did not detect the changes in my `.pro` file, and did not update the `Makefile`. The solution turned out to be three simple steps:

1. Create and use an icon in SVG 1.1 Basic format.
2. Add `ICON = youricon.svg` in the `.pro` file.
3. Delete the file `Makefile` and rebuild the application.

This worked for me. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Yes this is the way to do it, but do note that Symbian is quite picky about the .svg files it accepts. They need to be SVG-Tiny formatted, and even then they might not work. Try with very simple graphics and work upwards in terms of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If you think you have done all the right steps and your icon isn't too complex, try restarting your device. Symbian has some icon cache and it is updated on restart.

Comment: Thank you. This is already mentioned in a number of the links referenced in my question.